# conditional for sub category on archive page

Tags: categories, archives

I'm using conditional statements on my archives pages to display a different content depending of my categories.

I have 2 parent categories :

author
collections

each parent categorie has children categories

author-1
author-2 
and so on...

on my archive.php here is my code :

```
<?php if(is_category("collections")) : ?>

/* CONTENT FOR PARENT COLLECTION */

<?php endif; ?>
```

what I want is to be abble to target if its in a sub category of authors for example.

something like this :

```
<?php if(is_category("collections")) : ?>

/* CONTENT FOR PARENT COLLECTION */

<?php elseif(is_category("author")) : ?>

/* CONTENT FOR PARENT AUTHOR */

<?php elseif (*is_children_category_of*("collections")) ?>

/* CONTENT FOR CHILDREN COLLECTIONS */

<?php elseif (*is_children_category_of*("author")) ?>

/* CONTENT FOR CHILDREN AUTHORS */

<?php endif; ?>
```

I can't find any answer, does anybody know how to do this ?

thanks

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `cat_is_ancestor_of()` function.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/cat_is_ancestor_of

The example in the WP codex is very close to what you are attempting for your archive template.

```
<?php 
  // if the category is music or a music SUBcategory, 
   if (cat_is_ancestor_of( 4, $cat ) or is_category( 4 ) ):  ?>
   <div id="music_subnav_menu" class="subnav_menu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'Music' ) ); ?>
  </div>
 <?php endif; ?>
```